# Exit a query in a case statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to setup a query, so that it will compare two dates from two different tables, and if they are equal, then the query exits. If they are not equal, then the query will continue and insert some stuff. I can't figure out how to get it to do what I want however.

```
SELECT TOP(1) @dateA=a.someDate
FROM a
ORDER BY DESC;
SELECT TOP(1) @dateB=b.someDate
FROM b
ORDER BY DESC;

CASE WHEN @dateA=@dateB THEN raiseerror('dates equal',20,-1) with log;

Insert statements;
```

Any help would be super appreciated.

Comment: Some other variants of SQL have both an expression and a statement named `CASE` - SQL Server only has the `CASE` expression.

Comment: Do you actually _want_ to raise the error?  Or is that just an attempt at exiting?

Answer (score 16):

`CASE` is an expression (not a statement) and cannot be used for control-of-flow like that - not to call commands, not to return more than one column/value, not to be used as a command on its own.

It seems to me you can just use `IF` to raise the error when the dates are equal, otherwise run the inserts.

```
IF @dateA = @dateB 
BEGIN
  raiseerror('dates equal',20,-1) with log;
END
ELSE -- maybe you don't need a batch-aborting, logging error level
BEGIN
  INSERT ...
END
```

You could also do it the other way. Run the inserts only if the dates **are not equal**, otherwise raise the error:

```
IF @dateA <> @dateB
BEGIN
  INSERT ...
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  raiserror ...
END
```

If you thought to use the error *only* for the purpose of getting out of running the inserts, then you can just remove everything from `ELSE` down, since the only way the inserts will run is when `@dateA` and `@dateB` are **not equal**:

```
IF @dateA <> @dateB
BEGIN
  INSERT ...
END
```

I have scaled way back on being pedantic about things like rows (vs. "records"), and columns (vs. "fields"), but the whole expression vs. statement thing is a very important distinction, for exactly this reason. See "[Dirty Secrets of the CASE Expression](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression)."

Comment: Mostly a good answer, except for one nitpick..  Using the '<>' operator does not play well with NULL values.  If one of your date values is NULL, the 'not equal' operator will return unexpected results.  Try this "SELECT CASE WHEN (1 <> NULL) THEN '!=' ELSE '==' END"

Comment: @user5151179 I'm pretty sure Aaron knows the difference. Also check that the OP in the question says what he wants to do when the two dates are equal and what when they are not equal. He doesn't mention at all what they want to do when one or both of them are `NULL`. It's still a good observation that the two versions that Aaron provides will do different things in that case.

Answer (score 6):

Use an `IF` instead of a `CASE`

```
 IF @dateA=@dateB 
    raiseerror('dates equal',20,-1) with log;
 ELSE
    BEGIN
        Insert statements;
    END
```

This of course assumes that you actually want to raise an error.  The other option would be:

```
 IF @dateA<>@dateB 
    BEGIN
        Insert statements;
    END
```

Now, note the `BEGIN` and the `END`.  Those are going to be important.  the `IF` statement (and the `ELSE`) only affects the command right below it. If you need more than one command you need [a BEGIN and an END](https://sqlstudies.com/2017/10/04/the-alpha-and-the-omega-the-begin-and-the-end/).

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have pointed out that CASE is an *expression*, not a statement, and thus cannot itself encompass *statements* (like `RAISEERROR` or any others). If conditions are not many – particularly when it is just one condition, – the IF statement is the perfect choice for what you are trying to do, as has also been mentioned.

Nevertheless, depending on your scenario a CASE expression could still be used, just not exactly the way you have shown. In particular, if there are many conditions to be checked where a match should result in the same set of actions (e.g. raising an exception and terminating the script), you could use a CASE expression in an assignment statement storing the CASE's result, then follow it with an IF checking the stored result and performing the required action(s) if appropriate, like this:

```
DECLARE @ErrorMessage varchar(1000);

SET @ErrorMessage =
  CASE WHEN @dateA = @dateB THEN
    'Dates equal'
  CASE WHEN ... /* some other condition */ THEN
    'Some other message'
  .
  .
  .
  ELSE
    ''  -- no message if nothing is wrong;
        -- you can also omit the ELSE branch entirely,
        -- which means the same as ELSE NULL
  END
;

IF @ErrorMessage <> ''
BEGIN
  RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 20, -1) WITH LOG;
END;

... /* continue the script */
```

In this case the action needed is raising an exception, but the message returned with the exception needs to depend on what condition was checked first. The assignment statement uses a CASE expression to choose which message to store in the `@ErrorMessage` variable.

You can also see that the error is raised only conditionally – only if the variable actually contains a message to show. If the value is an empty string or a null, the script will just continue without interruption.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the variables?

```
declare @D1 table (dt date);
declare @D2 table (dt date);
insert into @D1 values ('2000-01-01'), ('2000-02-01');
insert into @D2 values ('2000-01-01'), ('2000-02-01');
if (select max(dt) from @D1) = (select max(dt) from @D2)
begin 
   select 'match'
end
else 
begin 
   select 'no match'
end
```